# PHP7.3: Update data in a class, from 2 other classes

Tags: php, class

I want to store some configuration in a class (data.class.php) that would be updated by (ClassOne.class.php) and the updated changes should be read by (ClassTwo.class.php).

The changes are visible from (ClassOne) but not from (ClassTwo).

**Question:** How can the changes in data.class.php be permanent so (ClassTwo) could see changes?

**File: run.php**

```
<?php

include("data.class.php");
include("ClassOne.class.php");
include("ClassTwo.class.php");

$class_one = new ClassOne();
$class_one->run();


$class_two = new ClassTwo();
$class_two->run();
```

**File: data.class.php**

```
<?php

class ConfigurationData
{

      public $http_components = [
        "method" => [
          "GET",     // [0] <-- Index
          "POST",    // [1]
          null       // [2]
        ]
      ];

}
```

**File: ClassOne.class.php**

```
<?php

class ClassOne extends ConfigurationData
{

    public function run()
    {
        $this->printDataPriorToInjection();
        $this->injectHelloInData();
        $this->printDataAfterInjection();
    }

    public function printDataPriorToInjection()
    {
      print_r($this->http_components);
    }

    public function injectHelloInData()
    {
      $this->http_components["method"][2] = "DELETE";
    }

    public function printDataAfterInjection()
    {
      print_r($this->http_components);
    }


}
```

**File: ClassTwo.class.php**

```
<?php

class ClassTwo extends ConfigurationData
{


    public function run()
    {
        // $this->printData();
    }

    public function printData()
    {
    print_r($this->http_components);
    }

}
```

Result:

// Result from [ClassOne.class.php]

```
Array
(
    [method] => Array
        (
            [0] => GET
            [1] => POST
            [2] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [method] => Array
        (
            [0] => GET
            [1] => POST
            [2] => DELETE
        )

)
```

// Result from [ClassTwo.class.php]

```
Array
(
    [method] => Array
        (
            [0] => GET
            [1] => POST
            [2] =>        // Comment. I would like DELETE to be visible.
        )

)
```

Comment: Make `$http_components` static, then it will be same for all instances.

Comment: @u_mulder It does work by changing the [$http_components] to static and calling $http_compoments by: [parent::$http_components] from [ClassOne.class.php] and [ClassTwo.class.php].

Answer (score 0):

propaply you should not extend the classes with the configuration class

make your configuration class as singleton.